# Xperia U: Network state is shown as UNKNOWN, data connection not working

Tags: data-connection, sony-xperia-u

I'm using stock Sony Xperia U. Data connection was working well until yesterday. All of a sudden I can't access 2G/3G data, it shows network state "UNKNOWN" when checked with the code `*#*#4636#*#*`.

I've tried flashing custom firmware, stock etc, but in all it shows network state "UNKNOWN"

Comment: Just fix it, then it will work again. (Sorry, but your question does not give enough details for a more precise answer: Did it happen "out of the blue"? What did you do right before it broke? What did you already try to fix it? Which settings have you checked, and what are they set to? Are you sitting in an atomics bunker where the signal cannot reach into? Does another device have data connection when placed next to it? Do you have a SIM card inserted at all?).

Comment: I've tried everything, tried checking APN, flashing new firmware, etc and yeah, I've a working data plan when checked on other devices, btw @Izzy I'm not sitting in an atomic bunker :P